# How to fix "image not being saved into my database(i.e image model field)"?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am building a Portfolio web app with Django.

I am unable to save an image into my database in my web app.

Also, to replace an existing image in the database does not work.

Note: I don't get any error message from Django. The web app will tell me no file being added.

On the Django Admin section(Django site administration page "localhost:8000/admin" I am able to add a new image and change an existing one.

How can I enable this functionality without going to django admin section.

Here's my code

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Jobs 

class JobsCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Jobs
    fields = ['image']
    template_name = "new_job.html"


class JobsUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Jobs
    fields = ['image']
    template_name = "change_job.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Jobs(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


def get_absolute_url(self):     
    return reverse('home', args=[str(self.id)])
```

If you need any additional information from me, please let me know or you can see the complete code of this [project here](https://github.com/coolpythoncodes/portfolio)

Comment: "[Firstly, in order to upload files, you’ll need to make sure that your <form> element correctly defines the enctype as "multipart/form-data"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)."

Comment: Thank you... It is now working.